# Switching from POP3 to IMAP in Sylpheed 3.2.0beta5

Tags: imap, pop3

I'm trying to switch my account settings from POP3 to IMAP, because I started to use my e-mail account on my smartphone and I want to know which messages I've already read.

The problem is I can't do it, because every option in server protocol settings is grayed out.

Is doing so impossible due to some inner workings or settings differences of POP3/IMAP?

I don't want to create new account in Sylpheed - I've got lots of filters and local folders, that I'd like to have and creating 'em all over again would be too time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it is I think by design; the same is true with Outlook and as such, my answer is about Outlook but it is still pertinent to your question.

After the account is created, it saves a .pst or .ost file. You can't then change the account type because the account type and associated data are not in the same format.